# Why is my lambda function not getting executed?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have the following function and this is called by main. But I don't see the lambda function being executed.

```
int LambdaTest(int x, int y, bool bLambda) {
 cout << "Lambda Rxd : " << bLambda << endl;
 if (bLambda) {
  return x + y;
 } else {
  return ((x > y) ? (x - y) : (y - x));
 }
}

int main() {
 int x = 10, y = 30;
 int val = -1;

 val = LambdaTest(x, y, [](int x) -> bool {
  return x > 15;
 });
 cout << "Lambda test 1: " << val << endl;

 val = LambdaTest(x, y, [](int y) -> bool {
  return y > 15;
 });
 cout << "Lambda test 2: " << val << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

In this main function my expectation is that the lambda function which is passed as third parameter of the function call shall execute and return true or false.

But I don't see the right value being passed to the function body.

Is there any extra need to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stateless lambda.

Stateless lambda can be converted to pointer to function. So your lambdas are converted into `void (*)(int)`, and this pointer is assigned to `bool` what gives always `true`.

To call lambda "in fly" you need to add `()` with parameter:

```
 val = LambdaTest(x, y, [](int x) -> bool {
  return x > 15;
 }(x) ); // <---
 cout << "Lambda test 1: " << val << endl;

 val = LambdaTest(x, y, [](int y) -> bool {
  return y > 15;
 }(y) ); // <---


[](){} -> bool ( /*here passed arguments */ );
```

Another solution is to store functor generated by lambda expression in some variable and then apply `()` on that object:

```
 auto l1 = [](int x) -> bool {
  return x > 15;
 };

 val = LambdaTest(x, y, l1(x));
 cout << "Lambda test 1: " << val << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks Rafix for the clarification.